# calling viewDidLoad after some delay

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

The scenario is as follows:

My application has a tabBarController on tapping a tab there occurs some parsing of XML from server which takes some time.The data recovered from parsing is gonna be there on the view of the selected viewController(i.e; the data is used in the viewDidLoad method).Now how can I ensure that the viewDidLoad method is called only when the parsing has been completed. Parsing is done in some delegate methods of the NSURLConnection class which gets called after some time the connection has established.In the meantime the viewDidLoad method gets called.

Comment: In order to give your user prompt feedback that they actually selected the tab (e.g. they didn't miss or the app doesn't appear to be broken), you might want to split your viewDidLoad with data into a viewDidLoad empty (maybe with an activity indicator spinning) and a viewLoadAndDisplayData, which can called by your URL load and parsing completion routine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you move your code from viewDidLoad into a custom function and then call **that** when your XML has been parsed?

for instance I have some applications where blog feeds/rss/xml are loaded into a UITableViewController and on `connectionDidFinish:` I just call `[tableView reloadData];` rather than trying to run `viewDidLoad` again.

Comment: Suppose I posted the notification when parsing is completed.But how will I delay the viewDidLoad??

Comment: you can't and shouldn't delay it. thats the whole point - if you want to delay some code then you need to put it into its own function and delay it. The whole point is it is called AS soon as the view loads.